# Is Elmer's rubber cement a viable choice for assembling Table Tennis Racket?

Tags: equipment, table-tennis, racket, maintenance

So I'm facing a dilemma, on one end my friend assembled his by looking on amazon for the highest rated water-based glue. On the other end, my other friend uses and recommends Elemer's rubber cement, because he claims it minimizes the damage done to the blade, which would be nice.

Wanted to see if Elmer's rubber cement, is a viable choice for gluing rubber on the blade.

Side note, did some further searching and started wondering...
is rubber cement equivalent to speed glue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elmer's Rubber Cement is the classic glue for Table Tennis Blades.  But it is no longer legal for tournaments.  If you glued within a week you will likely fail the sniff test for VOCs (solvents).
Water based glues are what you are supposed to use now.  Tear Mender, YES Paste and Elmer's no Drip School Glue are common choices now.